# react-phone-number-input validation failure

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to avoid submitting react form if any input errors occurs. But only for the phone number input field's validations which is handled by `react-phone-number-input` package I am having issues because it allows to submit even for invalid inputs. So I added `validate` property in rules object prop. But it throws me `parsePhoneNumber.js:18 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: A text for parsing must be a string.` My attempt is as below.

```
 <Controller
    name="phoneNum"
    render={({ field }) => (
      <SPhone
         label={Properties.TEL}
         {...field}
         error={errors.phoneNum && true}
         helperText={errors.phoneNum && errors.phoneNum.msg}/>
      )}
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    rules={{validate: (value) => isValidPhoneNumber(value)}}
 />
```

So what is the correct way to assign the rules prop to satisfy with the above phone number validation?

Comment: Use the error prop as mentioned in docs here: https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/

Comment: parsePhoneNumber.js:18 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: A text for parsing must be a string. To resolve this error pass value in isValidPhoneNumber as value.toString(). And invalidate check correct value is getting passed and what is the return value of isValidPhoneInput. Or else create a code sandbox so I can check.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Controller
name="phoneNum"
render={({ field }) => (
  <SPhone
     label={Properties.TEL}
     {...field}
     error={errors.phoneNum && true}
     helperText={errors.phoneNum && errors.phoneNum.msg}/>
  )}
control={control}
defaultValue=""
rules={{validate: (value) => isValidPhoneNumber(`${value}`)}}
/>
```

template string works for me.